# Note frequency fluctuation after fretting down the note? (electric guitar)

Tags: guitar

It has been 6 months since I've got my Jackson JS32 Kelly, and today I have noticed that after I fret down the E note on the 12th fret on the high E string, the note's frequency is fluctuating, and it sounds a bit annoying. Do you guys have any advice?

Comment: Can you post a recording and provide us with a link to it. Currently your post could refer to a number of things, so hearing the problem would really help narrow it down.

Comment: Damaged strings can cause this, but it's usually something I notice on lower strings.....

Comment: I have recorded the notes, it's quite obvious that some notes aren't ringing out correctly, and it's annoying.
Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6atxcmCFowFMzBzSFVjcGRrRE0

Comment: I tried to adjust the pickup height, checked the intonation, everything seems fine, and still this happens.

Comment: the last thing that cames to my mind, that maybe my strings are worn out a bit, since they are 5 months old, but I don't really think that this is the problem, because there's no rust on them + I was applying Dunlop String Cleaner on them for 4 and a half months.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that something on your guitar resonates near the high-E 12th fret frequency. Springs in the "tremolo" (vibrato) system for instance.

The best way to track something like this down is to put your finger on parts of the guitar while inducing the behavior and see if you can make it stop happening. Some things will be more clear when unamplified; some things you may need to get clever about, such as putting can headphones in contact with the body and play the note frequency on a loop so that the guitar resonates, but you can still hear any induced vibration.

Comment: I have inserted sponge parts between the springs, so there's no way they could resonate.